# Как получить массив значений у `input type = "number"` в JS?

Tags: javascript, html, веб-программирование

Как получить массив значений у `input type = "number"` в JS?

Допустим, есть HTML код: 
`<input type = "number">`
Пользователь ввел туда число "726".
Так вот, как мне получить массив, где индекс 0 = 7, 1 = 2, а 3 = 6?

Answer (score 1):

```js
document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("keyup", function(){
  let ar = this.value.split("");
  console.log(ar);
});
```

```html
<input type="number" id="test">
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function getArray() {
  var value = document.querySelector("input[type='number']").value;
  var arr = value.split("").map(i => +i);
  console.log(arr);
}
```

```html
<input type="number" value="726">
<button onclick="getArray()">Click</button>
```